# Running insert query for the first time getting duplicates due to E column and shouldn't insert duplicate records when you run for more than one time

Tags: oracle

[Based on values in D column, find out the match of D column values with A column values of same table. If matching exist, insert additional row of the entire matched row but with negative value in C column....I have added my code in comment also..I got stuck in between..This is the query I have used

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (A char, B char, C integer, D char, E integer);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('a', 'b', 10, 'c', 1);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('a', 'b', 10, 'c', 2);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('c', 'd', 20, ' ', 1);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('c', 'd', 20, ' ', 2);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('w', 'y', 40, 'j', 1);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('j', 'z', 50, ' ', 1);


   INSERT INTO TABLE1 
   SELECT A ,B, -1 *C , D, E
   FROM 
    ( SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D, T1.E
      FROM TABLE1 T1 
      INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.A = T2.D
    ) T
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 TT
                WHERE T.A = TT.A
                AND TT.C = -1 * T.C
             );
```

If I run the same insert query for the first time, it is populating duplicate records of the row (c, d, -20, 1) two times and (c, d, -20, 2) two times..actually I need only one time..This causes due to E column I feel so and when you run it for 2nd time the same query, it shouldn't insert duplicate records/..How do I remove duplicate records in the same table such that if same insert query runs for next time, it shouldn't get inserted existed record][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbWdV.png)

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO for your table (or create online fiddle) for reproducing the issue. Remove wrong DBMS tag.

Comment: Can someone help me in this query to get expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use all columns in the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 
   SELECT DISTINCT A ,B, -1 *C , D, E
   FROM 
    ( SELECT T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D, T1.E
      FROM TABLE1 T1 
      INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.A = T2.D
    ) T
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 TT
                WHERE T.A = TT.A AND T.B = TT.B AND T.D = TT.D AND AND T.E = TT.E
                AND TT.C = -1 * T.C
             );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7445b3359bf3ed252faaaba3b592699d)

Comment: Still I am getting duplicate records...Can you check once again? Actually 3 additional records need to be inserted but with your query, its getting 5 records inserted...for additional records, please check my image (it is highlighted with bold characters)

Comment: Ok, You need distinct as updated in the answer and also shared the DB<>FIDDLE